# Coupling problems in android screens

Tags: android, screen, layout-manager

I have a problem with the screens disenyo . Let me explain:

First, understand that there are 4 sizes (small , normal, large, xlarge ) .

Now I explain my case . I in my project I have all my
xml file in the folder from the folders layout and values ​​/ dimens.xml customized for each device determined the
Views positions , that is, for a screen :

```
-2.7 '' ( 240x320 ) ldpi : values ​​-small- ldpi
-3.2 '' ( 320x480 ) mdpi : values ​​-normal- mdpi
-3.3 '' ( 240x400 ) ldpi : values ​​-normal- ldpi
-3.7 '' ( 480x800 ) hdpi : values ​​-normal- hdpi
-3.7 '' ( 720x1280 ) xhdpi : values ​​-normal- xhdpi
large ...
```

however, these values ​​folder examples I fit perfectly , but what happens when the 'y ' variable for example :
`-3.7 '' ( 480x854 ) hdpi : values ​​-normal- hdpi` ? ? is out of position . Is, or do I make it Cuadre at 800 or 854 ..

How do I fix this?
There is some generic way to do this ?

You should not make just 4 sizes (small , normal, large, xlarge ) . ?

Thank you.

Comment: A set of four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and xlarge
Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based on the available screen width. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html